# how to get array values in select option inside <td> when row is generated on click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how to get array values in select option inside  when row is generated on click event? i tried this, the row is generated but the options are blank.
array values in var option. jush push same data 10 times. Am i using that forEach loop right way?
please help.

```js
$('#click').click(function() {
  $("#table tbody tr").remove();

  var r = 10;
  var option = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    option.push("<option>selectme</option>");
  }
  console.log(option);

  // for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  var td = "<tr><td>number</td><td>name</td><td><select>" +
    option.forEach(function(e) { e; }); +
    "</select></td></tr>";
  $("#table tbody").append(td);
  // }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="table" border="solid">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>s.no.</td>
      <td>name</td>
      <td>class</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>name2</td>
      <td>option</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button id="click">click</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

No. you used [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) the wrong way, because `forEach` always return `undefined`. In this case, you should use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#click').click(function () {
    $("#table tbody tr").remove();

    var r = 10;
    var option = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
      option.push("<option>selectme</option>");
    }
    console.log(option);

    // for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    var td = "<tr><td>number</td><td>name</td><td><select>" +
      option.reduce((acc, cur) =>
        acc + cur
      );
    +"</select></td></tr>";
    $("#table tbody").append(td);
    // }
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `forEach` but you need to do it little bit differently. First, create an empty `select` element and after that run `forEach` to create new `option` elements and append them to that `select`.

```js
$('#click').click(function(){
  $("#table tbody tr").remove();

  var r = 10;
  var option = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
      option.push("selectme");
  }

  var td = "<tr><td>number</td><td>name</td><td><select></select></td></tr>";
  $("#table tbody").append(td);

  const select = document.querySelector('select');
  option.forEach(v => {
      const o = document.createElement('option');
      o.textContent = v;
      select.appendChild(o);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table" border="solid">
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <td>s.no.</td>
          <td>name</td>
          <td>class</td>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>name2</td>
          <td>option</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button id="click">click</button>
```